# html-minifier: process inline scripts witout type

Tags: gulp, html-minifier

I am using html-minifier inside gulp to minify my html files. However, inline script tags without **type="text/javascript"** never get processed.

I've been searching in the documentation, but even the option **processScripts**, with **minifyJS**, was not able to solve it.

My script tags have no type, as it is not necessary in HTML5 (or am I wrong about this one?). What am I missing?

script.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.src('lib/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        processScripts: [undefined, null, ""],
    }))
    // .pipe(htmlmin({
        // collapseWhitespace: true,
        // minifyJS: true,
    // }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

---

EDIT

Running html-minifier directly in the string correctly minifies it. So, some sort of bug seems to be preventing options passed to gulp from arriving to html-minifier used internally.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following gulp project on an example html page that had inline scripts and html, with the parameter set to `minifyJS:true` it all worked. You are definitely looking at the correct parameter. Could it be that the way you are passing in your configuration parameters is not being recognised? Hopefully the example gulpfile code will help you somewhat.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
 
function defaultTask() {
        return gulp.src('src/*.html')
          .pipe(htmlmin({ 
              collapseWhitespace: true,
              minifyJS:true }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  }
  
  exports.default = defaultTask;
```

Comment: I changed my pipe to yours, and scripts remain intact. Indeed, only the first and last line-breaks are removed, but the rest of the script code does not change. The only difference is that I run the js file directly, but this should not be the source of the problem.